# Accessing rest of URI as PathVariable

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, uri

In my application I delete image by passing image id to REST api like this.

```
DELETE http://localhost:8080/connect/images/123456/abcdef
```

So, I mapped this with spring MVC as follows

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/images/{imageId}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE,
    produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseObject deleteImage(final HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request,   @PathVariable("imageId") final String imageId) {
        return ResponseUtil.executeInTryCatch(new ResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            public Object execute() throws Throwable {
                deleteImage(imageId);
                return "Image deleted successfully";
            }
        });
    }
```

But I am not able to fetch rest of URI after **images** to imageId path variable.
I want **imageId** should be `123456/abcdef`. Is there a way to extract using `@PathVariable` regular expression support?

Comment: But that solution doesn't work. I am still getting 404

Comment: The first answer does work. You cannot bind a part of the URI into a `@PathVariable` that contains a slash as it's a fully-reversed character in URI schemas (and file system paths/names). You need to either extract the identifier you need manually from `@RequestMapping("/images/**")` or, fix your implementation and stop sending slashes as part of an identifier - it's a stupid solution.